# jQuery using post for associative array

Tags: jquery

I need to post data to a URL like this:

```
http://www.your_domain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=68&qty=1&super_attribute[528]=55&super_attribute[525]=56
```

[See here for Magento documentation on query string](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring)

My current code looks like this, but it is not working.

```
var myObject = {
    super_attribute: {configOptionSuperAttribute: configOption}
};

        jQuery.post(productAddToCartURL, { product: productId, qty: qty, super_attribute: jQuery.param(myObject)  })
        .done(function(data) {
          alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
```

The issue is with the super_atribute[]. How do I make myObject compatible?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the value of `configOption`? Is it an array or object? How does it look like? The data is serialized using `jQuery.param` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). Have a look at the documentation to find out how to structure your object.

Comment: When you say "it is not working," what do you mean? Are you getting a JavaScript error? Is the call reaching the server? Is the done callback not firing?

Comment: Did you really use `jQuery.param` in your code or just now because I mentioned it? You should not call it explicitly, it's called internally by jQuery to serialize the whole data object. `myObject` in your update has to look like `configOption` in my answer. Don't make it more complicated than it is ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`jQuery.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) (which is used internally to serialize the data), your data should look like:

```
jQuery.post(
    productAddToCartURL, 
    {product: productId, qty: qty, super_attribute: configOption},
    function() { ... }
);
```

where `configOption` is an object of the form

```
var configOption = {
    528: 55,
    525: 56
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you pasted your code incorrectly, but your JavaScript has syntax errors. This is invalid because you have an unclosed quote. Perhaps you meant this:

```
jQuery
    .post(
        productAddToCartURL, 
        { product: productId, qty: qty, 'super_attribute[]': configOption })
    .done(function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); });
```

Or maybe this? (your `super_attribute[]` property name is weird):

```
jQuery
    .post(
        productAddToCartURL, 
        { product: productId, qty: qty, super_attribute: configOption })
    .done(function(data) { alert("Data Loaded: " + data); });
```